# Remix error "gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction" on private blockchain

Tags: remix, private-blockchain, gas-estimate

I'm trying to test contract interaction using Remix with two basic contract:

- contract Callee
- contract Caller

Callee function/variable:

```
uint[] public values;

function storeValue(uint value) {
    values.push(value);
}

function getValues() view returns(uint) {
    return values.length;
}
```

Caller function:

```
function storeAction(address addr) returns(uint) {
    Callee c = Callee(addr);
    c.storeValue(100);
    return c.getValues();
}
```

If I try to execute function "storeAction" I see a different behavior between:

- Remix Javascript VM: everything works fine
- Remix Web3 provider (http://localhost:8545):

> error "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below).
>   The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force
>   sending? gas required exceeds allowance or always failing transaction"

The deploy seems to works fine for both the environment.

I've already checked my private blockchain gas limit that is over 4700000.

Can someone explain this?

Thanks

Comment: Does the parameter "addr" contain the correct address?

Comment: Yes, it contains the address of the deployed contract Callee.

Comment: UPDATE: The instruction that falls is "c.getValues()" but I still don't understand why.

Answer (score 2):

I resolve the issue using version of solidity compiler earlier than ^0.4.21.